# I want to get the last available value in a previous row in MySQL8 in a calculated column

Tags: mysql-8.0

I have a table in mysql database this data.

```
id     date          close    previous_close
1      07-10-2020    200      300   
2      06-10-2020    300      1000
3      05-10-2020    0        1000
4      04-10-2020    1000     15
```

I've had a look at using the lag() function but can't get my head round it. How can I craft a query such that the calculated column `previous_close` obtains the most recently available value in the `close` column where it's not zero?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
        MAX(CASE WHEN close > 0 THEN date END) OVER
            (ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS last_date
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.date,
    t1.close,
    t2.close AS previous_close
FROM cte t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t2.date = t1.last_date
ORDER BY t1.date DESC;
```

The strategy here is that the CTE finds the latest date corresponding to a non zero close occurring strictly *before* each given row, as sorted by date.  Then, all we have to do is to join this CTE back to your original table to find the actual matching latest previous close value.

Comment: There's three tables here. `cte`, `t1` and `t2` is that right?

Comment: No...actually the only _table_ is your table, which I have called `yourTable`.